# Conflicting types for "function" error (C)

Tags: c, struct

I keep getting this error: [Error] conflicting types for 'average_grade'
and i cant find my mistake.. i am new in C so i really need some help here.

```
struct card {

    char on[20];
    char ep[20];
    float b;
    int ap;
    struct card *next;
};

struct card *first,*last,*t;

int ch;

int main()
{

    float mo;
    do {
        printf("\n1.Initialize\n2.Add to end\n3.Show list\n4.Average Grade\n0.Exit\nChoice:");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1: init_list(&first,&last);
                    break;
            case 2: t=create_node();
                    add_to_end(t,&first,&last);
                    break;
            case 3: show_list(first);
                    break;
            case 4: mo=average_grade(&first);
                    printf("%f",&mo);
                    break;              
            case 0: printf("Bye!\n");
                    break;
            default:printf("Try again.\n");
                    break;
        } /* switch */
    } while (ch!=0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

float average_grade(struct card *arxh)
{

    struct card *i;
    float sum=0;
    int cnt=0;
    for (i=arxh; i!=NULL; i=i->next)
    {
        sum= sum + i->b;
        cnt++;
    }
    return sum/cnt;
}
void init_list(struct card **arxh, struct card **telos)
{

    *arxh=NULL;
    *telos=NULL;
}

struct card *create_node()
{

    struct card *r;

    r=(struct card *)malloc(sizeof(struct card));
    printf("Give data:");
    scanf("%s %s %f %d",r->on,r->ep,&r->b,&r->ap);
    r->next=NULL;

    return r;
}

void add_to_end(struct card *neos,struct card **arxh,struct card **telos)
{

    if (*arxh==NULL)
    {
        *arxh=neos;
        *telos=neos;
    }
    else
    {
        (*telos)->next=neos;
        *telos=neos;
    }
} 

void show_list(struct card *arxh)
{

    struct card *i;

    for (i=first; i!=NULL; i=i->next)
        printf("%s %s %.1f %d\n",i->on, i->ep, i->b, i->ap);
}
```

Comment: If that is for C, why did you add a C++ tag?

Comment: That isn't all your code. What did you forward declare the function `average_grade` as?

Comment: C and C++ are completely same when it comes to functions at this point so i though that one with experience in C++ could help me..

Comment: 0) put function prototype before `main`. 1)`mo=average_grade(&first);` and `float average_grade(struct card *arxh)` not match function type.

Comment: Thats all my code.. scroll down..

Comment: i did that but i get the same error..

Comment: ok i solved this.. ty.. it had to about prototype function thanks..

Comment: `mo=average_grade(&first);` --> `mo=average_grade(first);`

Comment: C and C++ are _different_ languages. Do not include the other when asking for one. There are often subtle differences or different ways to solve a problem. For instance, in C++ `struct card` will also typedef `card`. In C `typedef struct card card` would be perfectly valid, as they reside in different namespaces. Also in C **do not cast `void *`**. In C++ you have to.

Comment: when calling malloc() (and family of functions) In C, do not cast the returned value.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: 'init_list()' should be eliminated (simply set the pointers to NULL where they are declared)  as the user could enter '1' after other nodes are created, resulting in the pointers being list, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf("%s %s %f %d",r->on,r->ep,&r->b,&r->ap);' 1) there is no max length modifier on the %s format/conversion specifiers.  So the user could easily overflow the input buffer for either of these fields.  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  in this case, the returned value must be '4'

Comment: your code should always use meaningful names, especially in struct definitions.  as it is, 'ep', 'on', 'b', and 'ap' are meaningless.   Before asking for input from the user, always output a very specific prompt.  the prompt 'printf("Give data:");' is meaningless to any user that has not idea just what data to input.

Comment: the code is missing the prototypes (place before the main() function) for all the sub functions.

Comment: when the user inputs a numeric value for a grade, the code needs to check that the value is >= 0 (and possibly <= 100) to assure the grade is valid.   If not valid, inform the user of the error and (perhaps) give them another chance to enter the values.

Comment: the code fails to pass all the malloc'd memory pointers to free() resulting in memory leaks

Answer (score 2):

In C, if there's no visible prototype found at the time of calling a function, compiler implicitly declares prototypes (pre-C99 -- Since C99, the implicit int rule has been removed)  with `int` return type.

But when the actual definitions are found later, their type (`float`s) conflict with the ones compiler declared for you. So, declare function prototypes at the beginning of the file (or put them in a header file) or move the functions above `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

As you do not pass more information, I suspect the error here:

> ```
> struct card *first
>   ...
> mo=average_grade(&first)
>   ...
> float average_grade(struct card *arxh)
> ```

You pass  `struct card **` ("pointer to pointer to struct ..") to a function requiring `struct card *` ("pointer to struct ..").

As you do not change `arxh`, you might want `mo=average_grade(first)`.

Notet that the prototypes are missing. I presume thy are given in advance of the posted code.

Note: You should always post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That example is far from that. You also show not if/wnat you tried to find out yourself.

**Hint:**

Always enable warnings. At least `-Wall` (for gcc) or similar for your compiler. More warnings can be helpful, check the available options of your compiler.